# vb.net radio button selection

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have the following in vb.net

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbEdit5" runat="server"  RepeatDirection="horizontal" >
  <asp:ListItem Value="1" >Yes</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="0" >No</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

I need to programatically select one of the 2 listitems.
How do I programatically select say 'Yes' above in vb.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
rbEditTop25.Items.FindByText("Yes").Selected = True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each li As ListItem In rbEditTop25.Items
     If li.Text= "Yes" Then
       li.Selected = True
     End If
Next
```

Comment: how do I programatically do this though?

Comment: Is this intended to be an answer??

Comment: Nice I hadn't used seen those methods previously.

Answer (score 0):

```
rbEditTop25.SelectedValue = "1"
```

Should do the trick!